# Update to Android Studio Chimpmunk: 'Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.3.3. Current version is 7.2.'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After update to Android Studio Chimpmunk, I get the error message on Gradle sync:

```
Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.3.3. Current version is 7.2.'
```

In my gradle-wrapper.properties, I have got :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
```

In my build.gradle, I have :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
```

I can't change it to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.3'
```

the latest version being found by Android Studio being 7.2.0

If I set:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2.0-bin.zip
```

I also get the same error (stangely).

I to fix this problem?

Thanks.

**ANSWER TO MY QUESTION :**

For now, I downgraded both to 7.0.4. Update will probably be possible soon.

Comment: Are you using the wrapper? What's in your Studio preferences -> build, execution, deployment -> build tools -> gradle?

Comment: Not exactly sure, but I think `7.4.2` is the required version, despite the error message tells otherwise. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73034758/5040556

Comment: the `dependencies` `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'` affect the gradle version needed. Downgrading it to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'` works!

Answer (score 56):

I just had this problem and invalidating cache fixed the issue.
File > Invalidate Caches...
[image: Image: Invalidate Cache and restart]

Comment: Nice. This is also works for error 'Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.4. Current version is 7.3.3.'

Comment: Thanks.  After setting the exact location for the newest gradle on the PC and syncing the project it was still giving the same problem. But invalidating cache is the last step in the solution.

Answer (score 8):

file/sync project with Gradle Files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 7):

I got this problem too after accepting an auto-update prompt from Android Studio. Weirdly, my machine synced OK but other people's didn't.

The gradle version requirement seems to be imposed by the Android gradle plugin (AGP) versions. So also look in your `build.gradle` files for this kind of thing:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0'
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0'
}
```

I found that the AGP version had got bumped to 7.2.0 by the update, and that must have a requirement of Gradle 7.3.3 (confusing!). Anyway, when I edited the AGP back to 7.1.3, then I could downgrade the base gradle `distributionUrl` to 7.2 and it all worked again.

So this is a compatible set of versions:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3'
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3'
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following :

1.- Open AndroidStudio

2.- Click on File -> Project Structure

3.- Set up the Gradle Version

4.- Clic on Apply and then Ok

[image: Screenshot Project Structure for gradle version]

I will hope it help

**Greetings from México**

Comment: I was looking for this kind of IDE solution. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have invalidated cache but it didnt help.

The problem of my setup was a two gradle-wrapper.properties files. Both of them should have same Gradle version but they had different.

```
yourproject/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

and

```
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

I set the same Gradle version for both of them to the

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip
```

After that issue has gone.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem for a project that i havent opened since december 2021, i fixed it by updating the `gradle` version to 7.4.2 in `gradle.wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip
```

and used **7.2.1** for the android gradle plugin version, i've also updated Android Studio to **Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1**.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue with a Cordova Android project.
Just go to File > Project Structure > Project (Android Studio Flamingo). Select a version of Gradle that works for you (drop down menu). Click Apply and the project should build now.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue for Gradle version 7.3.0 (Stable). This is how I solved the issue:

1. I changed the distribution URL present inside `gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

2. Then removed the following plugin present inside the `build.gradle` (app module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

3. Finally added this line to the `main/AndroidManifest.xml` to the activity section:

```
android:exported="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have to update to android studio dolphin first** (was on chipmunk).
This update support gradle version : 3.2 to 7.3, link here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Then update gradle-wrapper.properties :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
```

Then update your module dependencies as below

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
}
```

Optional : You will be asked to update gradle plugin to 7.3.1 so you can do it then your will have -> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'

That's all you need, no invalidate cache and restart or something else.

Answer (score 0):

So I've just had  the same problem with the incompatible required and current Gradle versions(followed the suggested **AGP** update). Going back to **v7.0.4** has fixed the issue.

However, the answer given by @***Khaled*** has also worked for me.

> File > Invalidate Caches > Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue when i had to update the iDE from chipmunk to flamingo, had faced AGP compatability issues, for that after some reading i found the following one useful in my case [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wYAF.png) where we can make this change in project level gradle

Answer (score -1):

Install new version Android Studio. It's working for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).